# Composer GOS Websocket bundle symfony 2.8 dependency trouble / Exception

Tags: composer-php, symfony-2.8

Hi i want to use gos websocket bundle but keep getting this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedMethodException: 
Attempted to call an undefined method named "setArgument" of class 
"Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition".
Did you mean to call e.g. "addArgument", "getArgument", "getArguments" 
or "setArguments"? in /var/www/vhosts/foo/vendor/gos/web- 
socket-bundle/DependencyInjection/CompilerPass/PingableDriverCompilerPass.php:37
```

so it seems the interface is not compatible with symfony 2.8 ? Here are the versions installed with composer

```
gos/pnctl-event-loop-emitter         v0.1.7             
gos/pubsub-router-bundle             v0.3.4             
gos/web-socket-bundle                v1.8.13            
gos/websocket-client                 v0.1.2 


symfony/symfony                      v2.8.11
```

anybody any idea what is the problem and what i can do from here idea?

Comment: You should probably upgrade Symfony - this method was introduced in version ~3.3. Or report this to package maintainer.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Thruway library](https://github.com/voryx/Thruway) for websockets in my project running on PHP 5.4 (works well with PHP 7 too). if you are in early stage of setting up websocket in your project I would recommend you to switch to Thruway, which has clear documentation and support.

Comment: well thanks for your answer but the application is already built based on autobahn / gos-websocket